# How to use zuul in spring cloud without spring boot actuator?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-netflix

I want to use zuul as a proxy server in my application, but I don't want to use spring boot actuator, I tried to remove it from the dependency as follow:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud-netflix.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

However, it will cause some ClassNotFoundException.
I don't need spring boot actuator in my application, but it has so many autoconfiguration in spring boot that will produce many endpoints that I don't want.
Is there any good way to solve this?

Comment: Can you be more specific about when the error occurs and more of your pom.xml so I can see what versions you are using?  I tried it with the following pom.xml and it started just fine. https://gist.github.com/spencergibb/2904bbb06d1b7240223e6313d9b9c451

Comment: I use the version of 1.1.2.RELEASE. And I think the problem is from org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.ProxyRequestHelper, it use TraceRepository from actuator. As if I remove this bean from ZuulProxyConfiguration, my application works.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: FWIW, you can separate these endpoints to a non-public port by setting management.port=<private port> in application.properties

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been addressed in [spring cloud netflix 1135](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1135). It will be available shortly in Brixton.SR2.